# Django installation using Virtualenv gone wrong

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, virtualenv

So i have been playing around with python (2.7.x) and django framework on my ubuntu (12.04). The way i setup django based project is by using virtualenv

Which i did it like this

```
** FROM TERMINAL **
1. sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
2. sudo easy_install virtualenv
```

Then i continue setting up my directory for my django project by using this command:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages project-name
```

Soon after that, i activated my virtualenv:

```
source project-name/bin/activate
```

Then i continue with the Django framework installation using this:

```
sudo easy_install Django
```

and verify that Django framework is installed within my virtualenv by checking there is a file called django-admin.py under project-name/bin/ directory (which is exists).

However, the second time i tried to create another django-project (completely different one) following the same exact step as above, I don't have django-admin.py installed in the correct directory. It's get installed to /usr/lib/python...

And when i tried to run the app i get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Thanks.

*** EDITED PART ***

responding to sachitad's answer

i get the following message when i executed his/her suggestion

```
(project-name)blah@blah:~/Documents/python/project-name$ easy_install django
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/blah/Documents/python/project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-3775.write-test'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/home/blah/Documents/python/project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

that's why, i initially thought i need to use the sudo command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an addition to sachitad answer, I suggest you have a look at [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which allow you to manage easily you virutal env with commands like :

```
mkvirtualenv your_project_name // create a virtual environment
workon your_project_name // select this virtual environment

pip install django // will install in this virtualenv
```

Comment: Do i need to install pip or easy_install inside this virtual environment?

Comment: You can either use `pip` or `easy_install` to install python packages inside or out the `virtualenv.` I recommend `pip` as it has several advantages over `easy_install`.

Comment: So, i pratically give up with virtualenv --no-site-packages, and decided to use your solution. It works with some adjustment (as described on virtualenvwrapper site). Cheers mate.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

```
sudo easy_install Django
```

Even if you have activated the virtualenv, while installing packages inside virtualenv, **never ever** use `sudo`. If you use sudo, it assumes you are installing on the system path`(/usr/lib/local/..)`.

Thus,

```
easy_install django
```

**OR**

```
pip install django
```

should work.

Comment: It's his :) Oh, well it turns out your project directory inside don't have write access. Give the write access and you should be fine.
`chmod -R u+rw project_name`

Comment: I am getting a bunch of messages like this
chmod: changing permissions of `project-name/local': Operation not permitted

When i did ls -l, this is what i get drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Okt  4 13:45 project-name

Comment: `sudo chmod -R u+rw project_name`

Comment: I still get the same error message. I will try to remove the project folder. And create it from scratch again. Otherwise i will try using Eliot's suggestion.

Comment: you need to do `chown -R blah:yourgroup project_name`

Comment: How about? `sudo chmod ugo+rw project_name`

Answer (score 0):

./home/user/path_to_virtual_env_project_/bin/pip install Django

you call pip which not in virtual env.
It seems activate not work.